# Response message: Composite message or optional fields

Tags: web-services, architecture, service, message, n-tier-architecture

We are working with a set of web services and we're looking for the best option to return errors to the web service's consumer. This is the current response:

#### Response

- Some data about the server
- Some data about the user
- **Some resulting data of executing the transaction**

So, we need to return errors too. these are our options:

#### Composite message

we'll return two kinds of responses depending if the transaction was approved or had an error:

First:

- type identifier (this message is serialized. so I need to know which kind of message I'm dealing with, to deserialize the last part)
- Some data about the server
- Some data about the user
- **Some resulting data of executing the transaction**

Second:

- type identifier (this message is serialized. so I need to know which kind of message I'm dealing with, to deserialize the last part)
- Some data about the server
- Some data about the user
- **The errors**

#### Optional fields

the transaction data and error fields will be optional. if there's no errors I will know it was approved.

- Some data about the server
- Some data about the user
- **Some resulting data of executing the transaction**
- **The errors**

#### Which option is more appropriate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is discutable and more of a personal opinion than a best practice.

My personal favor is to use the **Optional fields**, because the error code is possible outcome of an operation. I would expect the client to always first check the (optional) error properties of the returned result before parsing the results. This allows to also return *non-fatal* errors and partial results together. Exclusive makes it so ... exclusive. Optional is more flexible.

Comment: thank you, Kroonwijk, the partial results case is a really good point in favor of optional fields. I hadn't realize it. +1